# Migration from swift 2 to swift 3 errors

Tags: swift, string, swift3

the below code was working fine in swift 2 but showing error "missing argument for parameter #1 in call" after migrating to swift 3.

```
@IBOutlet weak public var countryTextField: UILabel!

var country_code = self.countryTextField.text!.characters.dropFirst() // missing argument for parameter #1 in call
```

Comment: Can you post declaration of IBOutlet countryTextField?

Comment: Strange - Created project with label and run this code without any issues. Clean build ?

Comment: @NickCatlib was working fine in swift2

Comment: Yeah, I agree - even if you create new project with this setup it will work. That is why I proposed to clean and then build again

Comment: @NickCatlib still not working after cleaning and building

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas Can you add more code.

Comment: @NiravD have added code

Comment: The error is misleading. You can't run this code outside a function or method.